# how to arrange the list elements by splitting the element .?

Tags: tcl

here is the list

```
"_7_to_0_k1"
"_7_to_0_k3"
"_7_6_5_0_k4"
"_3_2_k6"
"_4_3_2_1_k4"
"_1_k5"
"_3_2_k5"
"_0_k5"
"_3_2_k7"
"_4_k5"
"_5_k5"
"_7_6_k5"
"_7_6_k6"
"_7_to_0_k2"
"_7_6_k7"
```

to be sorted to

```
"_7_to_0_k1"
"_7_to_0_k2"
"_7_to_0_k3"
"_7_6_5_0_k4"
"_0_k5"
"_4_3_2_1_k4"
"_1_k5"
"_3_2_k5"
"_3_2_k6"
"_3_2_k7"
"_4_k5"
"_5_k5"
"_7_6_k5"
"_7_6_k6"
"_7_6_k7"
```

note : in this list 7_to_0 represents 7_6_5_4_3_2_1_0
tried this custom sort to sort by last two characters but i think i need to modify it to search for the whole string.

```
proc sort_by_last_two {a b} {
    set a_last_two [string range $a end-1 end]
    set b_last_two [string range $b end-1 end]
    return [string compare $a_last_two $b_last_two]
}
set sorted_list [lsort -command sort_by_last_two $my_lis]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a "decorate-sort-undecorate" technique:

```
set theList {"_7_to_0_k1" "_7_to_0_k3" "_7_6_5_0_k4" "_3_2_k6" "_4_3_2_1_k4" "_1_k5" "_3_2_k5" "_0_k5" "_3_2_k7" "_4_k5" "_5_k5" "_7_6_k5" "_7_6_k6" "_7_to_0_k2" "_7_6_k7"}

set decorated [lmap elem $theList {list $elem [lrange [split $elem "_"] end-1 end]}]
set decoratedSorted [lsort -index end $decorated]
set sortedList [lmap item $decoratedSorted {lindex $item 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom comparison function to `lsort` that takes into account the entire string.

```
proc customCompare {a b} {
    set lastA [lindex [split $a "_"] end]
    set lastB [lindex [split $b "_"] end]
    return [expr {$lastA - $lastB}]
}

set inputList {"_7_to_0_k1" "_7_to_0_k3" "_7_6_5_0_k4" "_3_2_k6" "_4_3_2_1_k4" "_1_k5" "_3_2_k5" "_0_k5" "_3_2_k7" "_4_k5" "_5_k5" "_7_6_k5" "_7_6_k6" "_7_to_0_k2" "_7_6_k7"}

set sortedList [lsort -command customCompare $inputList]

puts $sortedList
```

It splits the elements on underscore character and compares the last parts numerically. Then, it sort the list based on this custom comparison function.